# Newbie Help: Black screen after ubuntu upgrade (in a dual boot scenario)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade

I am having a lot of trouble getting my dual boot ubuntu 20.04 /windows 10 running again after an upgrade to ubuntu. Essentially, now when I boot I don't see the grub menu and it goes directly to try to boot ubuntu but all I see are a bunch of messages on a black screen that say things like [Failed to start Plymouth Boot Screen] or [Failed to start CUPS scheduler] etc. It then just stops at a black screen. I can access the grub menu by pressing shift during loading which let's me access windows OK, but I can't log in at all to Ubuntu. Does anyone know how I can get a log in screen back for Ubuntu? I have tried sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop but this doesn't work. Any ideas???? Many thanks in advance!

I can access the terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F5. I have ethernet connection working and I can access all my files. I just need someone to help me get a desktop working again. Not sure what went wrong?

My other option is to reinstall Ubuntu but I don't want to lose data or have to recreate a bunch of virtual environments I created with conda. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Boot from live cd or usb copy all important data off, reinstall from scratch. In the long run that will be much faster then trying to fix a mess and much more stable as well.